# Day and year Reversed VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare dates in a vba script I wrote however I am having an issue where the date when put into the format function reads the day as the year and the year as the day. You can imagine this throws of the script significantly and thus causes many error. The Date values in question are formatted as dates as I have ran them thru the IsDate function and returned a true value.

When I call the value these are the values generated in the immediate window.[image]

When I convert format using Format(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value,"dd-MM-yy") I recieve the following data in the immediate window.

[image]

The following is the script where I compare them in the immediate window and where I got the photos used in this post from.

```
Sub Rem9()
Dim i As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 wsName = ws.Name

 lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  FirstDateRead = CDate("1, 1,2018") 'Initialize the first Day of the year as the last day

For i = 1 To lr
Debug.Print FirstDateRead
Debug.Print CStr(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value)

Debug.Print DateDiff("m", ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, FirstDateRead)

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, please show some code so we can help you. Also, this might be an interesting read [mcve]

Comment: @Stefan I included the code for the process however the main issue is with the formatting or changing of the data and how I could solve it in my script.

Comment: Have you checked the date provided by `CDate`? is it DD-MM-YY or MM-DD-YY? Similarly what format are the dates in the cells?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad provides 2021-02-17 which has the day and year reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just fix the date format

```
Function FixDateFormat(strDate As String) As String
    Dim datePartsArray
    datePartsArray = Split(strDate, "-")
    FixDateFormat = datePartsArray(1) & "-" & datePartsArray(0) & "-" & datePartsArray(2)
End Function
```